# How to get how much roles created, Audit Logs (discord.js)

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want to check how many roles were created after 3 seconds, but `filtered.size` logs undefined, how can I accomplish this?

```js
wait(3000)

const logs = await guild.fetchAuditLogs({ type: 'ROLE_CREATE', });
if( !logs) return;
        
const entry = logs.entries;
const filtered = entry.filter(e => e.createdAt = Date.now());
console.log(filtered.size);
```

Comment: `logs.entries` returns a collection, so I should be able to just call `.size`.

Comment: You probably want to filter by `e.createdAt === Date.now()`. A single equals sign just assigns the value, two or three equals signs check if the values are equal.

Comment: SIngle `=` assigning to a new value, `==` or `===` to check if the value is equal, `!=` for not equal

Comment: That is not why the code was faulty

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Note: This code is written for @discordjs/collection v0.7.0 and discord.js v13.8.1*

---

## `<Collection>.entries` is not a property

A Discord.js [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/0.7.0/class/Collection) is a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) with a few extra functions. As stated on the documentation, a function exists called [`entries()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/0.7.0/class/Collection?scrollTo=entries). Due to this, two issues arise.

- Since the `entries` property does not exist on the [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/0.7.0/class/Collection), your code is returned a function. The code attempts to run `filter` on the function, which returns undefined because `Function.filter()` doesn't work.
- Even if `log` was updated to have `<Collection>.entries` as a function, this would still return an error as `.entries(...).filter` is not a function ([Demonstrated here on Runkit](https://runkit.com/embed/8vrhvi19ufsn))

## Solution

### Use the built in [`filter`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/0.7.0/class/Collection?scrollTo=filter) function

On the Collection docs, there is a function called [`filter`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/0.7.0/class/Collection?scrollTo=filter) which works similarly to [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Due to this, it's possible to skip creating filtered. If you still keep the `entry` variable, you'd just convert `.entries` to `.entries()`. It'd look something like this:

```js
// Skip creating the entry variable
const filtered = logs.filter(e => e.createdAt === Date.now());

// Or, if you'd like to keep the variable
const entry = logs.entries();
const filtered = entry.filter(e => e.createdAt === Date.now());
```

Also, in your use of `filter(...)`, you are using a single `=` which sets the [`createdAt`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/13.8.1/class/GuildAuditLogsEntry?scrollTo=createdAt) property of the log to `Date.now()`. In order to solve this, I've used `===` which only selects entries where the [`createdAt`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/13.8.1/class/GuildAuditLogsEntry?scrollTo=createdAt) property is **strictly** set to `Date.now()`.

### Convert `.entries` to a function and sort it as an Array

First, we need to change the `entries` to `entries()`. After that, we will use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to convert the [IterableIterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) returned from [`Collection.entries()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/0.7.0/class/Collection?scrollTo=entries) into an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) that we can filter. After that, we'll use the same `filter` function used in the above solution.

```js
const entry = logs.entries();
const filtered = Array.from(entry).filter(e => e.createdAt === Date.now());
```

Comment: I solved this about a few hours after it posted but the solution was this. Thanks for the in-depth explanation understand it more now.

Comment: Using `entries` as a property is something I've done as well, I'll admit. Hopefully this helps out future people. Also be careful with using a single `=` as pointed out a few times.